# How do I know an Excel application property has changed (Ex: UseSystemSeparator) or a custom Tab have been selected?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ribbon, property-binding

We use both french and english software on our computer and we ofthen need to switch from "." to "," as the decimal separator. To facilitate this, I'm building a Excel custom Ribbon using C# Visual Studio 2017. I have put on my Ribbon a Tab, a Check Box to change the UseSystemSeparators property of the Excel application, and 2 edit box to display and modify the  DecimalSeparator and the ThousandsSeparator properties as well. When the user change the value of the controls, the PropertyChanged event of the control is triggered and I update the application properties accordingly. Everything work fine. The problem araise when the user manually go in Excel and change the advance option, the controls on my Tab are not automatically updated. So is there a way to :

EITHER Catch an event that rise when the property UseSystemSeparators is modified so I can update my controls?

OR Catch an event that rise when my custom Tab is selected so I can update my controls when it is displayed?

OR Bind the application property to the control property?

So far, I have found nothing that can help me in either way. The UseSystemSeparators do not rise any event and I haven't found any way to know when my custom Tab is being displayed. Note that I use the Ribbon Designer to built my custom ribbon (Not XML).

Below is the code I use to update the application properties from the control.

```
private void ChkUseSysteme_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application excelObj = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        if (chkUseSysteme.Checked)
        {
            excelObj.UseSystemSeparators = true;
            ebDecimal.Enabled = false;
            ebMilliers.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            excelObj.UseSystemSeparators = false;
            ebDecimal.Enabled = true;
            ebMilliers.Enabled = true;
        }

    }

    private void EbDecimal_TextChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application excelObj = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        if (!excelObj.UseSystemSeparators)
        {
            excelObj.DecimalSeparator = ebDecimal.Text;
        }
        excelObj = null;

    }

    private void EbMilliers_TextChanged(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application excelObj = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        if (!excelObj.UseSystemSeparators)
        {
            excelObj.ThousandsSeparator = ebMilliers.Text;
        }
        excelObj = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no such events you could subscribe to. But as an idea, you may consider utilizing the timer to check the value of `UseSystemSeparators` periodically (e.g. every 1 second) and take the action accordingly.